# Session hash in rails turning into a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication

For some reason after some time on my website my session hash is turning into a string

```
undefined method `admin?' for "#<Visitor:0x000001071b7800>":String
```

is what I'm getting in my `render_layout` method

```
def render_layout
  if session[:visitor].admin?
    render layout: 'admin'
  else
    render layout: 'application'
  end
end
```

the only two other times I ever call or use session[:visitor] is in my `authenticate` method, and my `logged_in?` method that i use to skip `authenticate`

```
def authenticate
  uuid = params[:uuid]
  @visitor ||= uuid && Visitor.find_by_uuid(uuid)
  if !@visitor
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |login, password|
      @visitor = Visitor.find_by_uuid(ENV['ADMIN_UUID']) if login == 'test' &&  password == 'testpw'
    end
    session[:visitor] = @visitor
  else
    session[:visitor] = @visitor
  end
end

def logged_in?
  !!session[:visitor]
end
```

Why is this getting turned into a string? I used a project search in atom and I only ever called it in those places.

#### Edit:

I've added a `binding.pry` at the 4 locations I call session[:visitor] and it works the first time through everything. As soon as I follow a url for the first time and

```
before_action :authenticate, unless: :logged_in?
```

gets called for a second time the `session[:visitor]` is turned into a string

```
#=> "#<Visitor:0x00000106851bd0>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sessions

> Do not store large objects in a session. Instead you should store them
>   in the database and save their id in the session. This will eliminate
>   synchronization headaches and it won't fill up your session storage
>   space (depending on what session storage you chose, see below). This
>   will also be a good idea, if you modify the structure of an object and
>   old versions of it are still in some user's cookies. With server-side
>   session storages you can clear out the sessions, but with client-side
>   storages, this is hard to mitigate.

Store your visitor's ID in the session

```
session[:visitor_id] = @visitor.id
```

and then retrieve it as needed

```
@visitor = User.find_by_id(session[:visitor_id])
```